# How do I find Biology.SE's vital statistics?

Tags: support, feature-request

Apologies if this is obvious, but I've had a look around and can't see it anywhere.

I notice that some of the beta SEs listed on Area51 have summary statistics for users, average questions/day, % answered, etc ([example](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning)). Is it possible to get this information for sites that are out of beta? Specifically, Biology.SE?

Comment: Hmm. On reflection I'm wondering if this belongs on Meta.SE. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think it is also fine here, but you will probably already find an answer of at meta.SE. For me no reason to close or move

Answer (score 4):

You can find some basic statistics about all sites on http://stackexchange.com/sites

If you have at least 25k reputation or are a mod, you can see detailed site statistics at https://biology.stackexchange.com/site-analytics

This page contains e.g. this graph about the post volume over time:

[image]

If you're interested mostly in traffic, but don't have 25k reputation, you can see detailed traffic statistics on Quantcast: https://www.quantcast.com/biology.stackexchange.com

If you're not intimidated by some SQL, you can write a query on the Data Explorer (http://data.stackexchange.com/) to create even more statistics.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! So (as of 20th July 2016): 85% answered is between 'healthy' and 'needs work';  size of user community is definitely in the 'excellent' range; number of answers per (answered) question is roughly 1.3, so also needs work; daily visits is at least 10k so no problems there.

Comment: @arboviral The %answered is in the "needs work" range for most of the graduated, healthy SE-sites. Most sites having >90% are beta sites wanting to graduate (after having special efforts to push the %answered higher).

Comment: @arboviral I really wouldn't focus that much on the A51 stats, they're not really all that useful.